# Weird text position in my simple code

Tags: javascript, html, css

Problematic code here:

```
#container {  /*CSS part*/
  width: 606px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px #434343 solid;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border-top: none;
}

#tabs {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#tabs li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
}

#content {
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.subtab {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#tab1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#tab2 {
  background-color: red;
}

#tab3 {
  background-color: green;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
}

<div id="container"> <!-- html part -->
<ul id="tabs">
  <li id="blue">blue</li>
  <li id="red">red</li>
  <li id="green">green</li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
  <div id="tab1" class="subtab">This is tab1!</div>
  <div id="tab2" class="subtab">This is tab2!</div>
  <div id="tab3" class="subtab">This is tab3!</div>
</div>
```

```
var tablist = document.getElementById('tabs').children; //js part
var sublist = document.getElementsByClassName('subtab');

for (var i = 0; i < tablist.length; i++) {
  tablist[i].index = i; //保存每次迭代的i值

  tablist[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    for (var x = 0; x < sublist.length; x++) {
      sublist[x].style.display = 'none';
    }

    sublist[this.index].style.display = 'block';
    this.style.borderBottom = 'none';
  })
}
```

Sorry seems the html part doesn't come out right, markdown is always a pain for me.

full code here
**[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNGYKr)**

The weird thing is the text position of tab content(subtab class), if you click in an order of blue->red->green, the text shows fine in the center, however, if you click green first the text will show up right-aligned, then you click blue then you will find that the text position will be the right place.

There are several situations around this, but basically this is the matter.

Why??

Comment: post code here, makes it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the height of the `<ul>` element (the tabs container). You have specified:

```
#tabs {
    height: 100px;
}
```

and

```
#tabs li {
    height: 100px;
}
```

But you **did not take into account the 2 additional pixels for the borders**.

### Fix

To fix this, change the height of the `<ul>` element to `102px`:

```
#tabs {
    height: 102px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Great debugging! Can you explain how did you find the problem? I just got no idea where to start to locate the problem. thx a looooot

Answer (score 1):

I just added `text-align` rule to the `.subtab`class, like so:

```
.subtab {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

then, in the JS, comment out the

```
this.style.borderBottom = 'none';
```

worked perfectly

Comment: Seems the problem remains to me

Comment: @DrakeXiang updating answer, found problem

Comment: Thanks, this is also a solution

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to your #content id by specifying the position and width and it should be working well now:

```
#content {
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Great approach, this seems the best solution, although I was interested in how did the bug happen, thx anyway

Answer (score 1):

It's problem of box-sizing you can fix this by add below class to your  CSS

```
div#container, div#container * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

you can more about box-sizing https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Working Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/duk4xwnm/)

Just added `position:absolute;` and `width:100%;` to your `.subtab` css rule

Below is the code Snippet.

Final .subtab is

```
.subtab {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
}
```

```js
var tablist = document.getElementById('tabs').children;
    var sublist = document.getElementsByClassName('subtab');
    
    for (var i = 0; i < tablist.length; i++) {
      tablist[i].index = i; //store the i value for every iteration
      
      tablist[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        for (var x = 0; x < sublist.length; x++) {
          sublist[x].style.display = 'none';
        }
        
        sublist[this.index].style.display = 'block';
        this.style.borderBottom = 'none';
      })
    }
```

```css
#container {
      width: 606px;
      height: 400px;
      border: 1px #434343 solid;
      border-radius: 7px;
      border-top: none;
    }
    
    #tabs {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    #tabs li {
      float: left;
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      line-height: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
    }
    
    #content {
      height: 300px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .subtab {
      display: none;
      height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      position:absolute;
      width:100%;
    }
    
    #tab1 {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    
    #tab2 {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    #tab3 {
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    #blue {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    
    #red {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    #green {
      background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<body>
 <h1>simple tab</h1>
  <div id="container">
    <ul id="tabs">
      <li id="blue">blue</li>
      <li id="red">red</li>
      <li id="green">green</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="tab1" class="subtab">This is tab1!</div>
      <div id="tab2" class="subtab">This is tab2!</div>
      <div id="tab3" class="subtab">This is tab3!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
</body>
```